# If $f(t) = |f(t)|(\cos \theta (t),\sin \theta (t)), \forall t\in [a,b]$ is of class $C^k$, then so is $\theta(t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2-\{0,0\}$ be a path of class $C_k$
>   (continuous derivative). Show that if a continuous function
>   $\theta:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that
>
> $$f(t) = |f(t)|(\cos \theta (t),\sin \theta (t)), \forall t\in [a,b]$$
>
> Then $\theta$ is of class $C^k$

The derivative of this path is

$$f'(t) = (-|f(t)|\sin\theta(t)+sign(t)f'(t)\cos (\theta(t)),|f(t)|\cos\theta(t)+sign(t)f'(t)\sin (\theta(t)))$$

right? Or did I miss something?

Now, if $f$ is or order $C_k$, then its derivative is of order $C^{k-1}$, which means that that giant thing is $C^{k-1}$. I've been thinking about some way to relate the continuity of the derivative of the giant thing and the continuity of the derivative of $\theta(t)$, but how to do it?

Should I just say that the product of continuous functions is continuous and so $\theta(t)$ must be? Because, is there a way for the giant thing to be continuous without $\theta(t)$ being?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the derivative of $\theta(t)$. Anyway, you can write it in complex form inasmuch $f$ is written in modulus-argument from (or polar form).

$g(t)=r(t)e^{i\alpha(t)}$ with $r(t)=\vert f(t)\vert$ and $\alpha(t)=\theta(t)$

$g'(t)=r'(t)e^{i\alpha(t)}+i\alpha'(t)r(t)e^{i\alpha(t)}$

Now, if $g$ is $C_1$, $\alpha(t)$ is $C_1$ and so on. For each successive derivative of $f(t)$ we only need to keep track of the term with the higher derivative in $\alpha(t)$

$g''(y)\to i\alpha''(t)r(t)e^{i\alpha}$ etc.

Comment: Why it follows that $g$ is $C^1$ then $a(t)$ is $C^1$?

Comment: Can I say explicitly that it's because the product of continuous functions is continuous? Also can I ensure everything involved in these products are continuous?

Comment: Yes. Product and composition of continuous functions are continuous. Only lasts $\alpha'$, so if $g'$ is continuous, $\alpha'$ has to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a purely local theorem. Assume for simplicity that for some $t_0\in[a,b]$ we have $x(t_0)>0$. Then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $t_0$ such that $x(t)>0$ for all $t\in U$, and an integer $n$ such that
$$\theta(t)=2n\pi +\arctan{y(t)\over x(t)}\qquad(t\in U)\ .$$
Since $\arctan$ and rational functions are $C^\infty$ we can conclude that $t\mapsto\theta(t)$ is at least $C^k$ in $U$.